# split a file based on similar row headings

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

Could someone please help me write a script for the following requirement in awk,grep,sed,perl,or python?

Input file "raw.fa" :

```
>CLocus_1_Sample_61_Locus_1_Allele_0 [JPKM01095229.1, 31450, +]
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGATTGGAG
>CLocus_1_Sample_67_Locus_1_Allele_0 [JPKM01095229.1, 31450, +]
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGATTGGAG
>CLocus_1_Sample_107_Locus_1_Allele_0 [JPKM01095229.1, 31450, +]
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGATTGGAG
>CLocus_1_Sample_107_Locus_1_Allele_1 [JPKM01095229.1, 31450, +]
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGGTTGAAG
>CLocus_41_Sample_158_Locus_53_Allele_0 [JPKM01105094.1, 1700, +]
TGCAGGTTATCCAGCTCTATTCTGCACTGGCCATCGTACCAAATAGCAGGAGGGT
>CLocus_41_Sample_159_Locus_31_Allele_0 [JPKM01105094.1, 1700, +]
TGCAGGTTATCCAGCTCTATTCTGCACTGGCCATCGTACCAAATAGCAGGAGGGT
>CLocus_86_Sample_161_Locus_103_Allele_0 [JPKM01106288.1, 770, -]
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACACACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
>CLocus_86_Sample_164_Locus_98_Allele_0 [JPKM01106288.1, 770, -]
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACACACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
>CLocus_86_Sample_166_Locus_110_Allele_0 [JPKM01106288.1, 770, -]
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACTCACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
>CLocus_86_Sample_167_Locus_123_Allele_0 [JPKM01106288.1, 770, -]
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACTCACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
```

I would like to split the above file by locus, with 1 file per locus, keeping the DNA (second row) and sample # from the first row, producing three separate .fa files:

"locus1.fa" :

```
>Sample_61
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGATTGGAG
>Sample_67
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGATTGGAG
>Sample_107
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGATTGGAG
>Sample_107
TGCAGGTGTGTTCTGCAGATCCAAACACAAAGAGGCAGGGGTTGAAG
```

"locus41.fa" :

```
>Sample_158
TGCAGGTTATCCAGCTCTATTCTGCACTGGCCATCGTACCAAATAGCAGGAGGGT
>Sample_159
TGCAGGTTATCCAGCTCTATTCTGCACTGGCCATCGTACCAAATAGCAGGAGGGT
```

"locus86.fa" :

```
>Sample_161
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACACACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
>Sample_164
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACACACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
>Sample_166
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACTCACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
>Sample_167
TGCAGGGAACCGTGCTCAGCTCTGGAGTATTCCCACTCACTTGGCTCCCATTGGGATGACTCCTTT
```

Thanks for your help! I've found awk code to split by first occurrence, but not how to split groupings of similar rows (e.g. all rows with header of locus86 and their second row DNA sequence).

-Chris Martin

Comment: Have you written any code in any programming language to try to solve the problem yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a small set of "locus" values, you could grep for them:

```
grep -A 1 locus86 raw.fa > locus86.tmp
```

and then reformat the line:

```
sed 's/>.*(Sample .*)_Locus_.*/\1/' locus86.tmp > locus86.fa
```

(obviously you can combine those with a pipe rather than use an intermediate file).

If you have a larger or unknown set of locus values, scripting in something like perl would make sense.  With the caveat that it can be expensive to open/close files, here's some pseudo code:

```
open(IN, "raw.fa");
my $OUT = undef;
while (<IN>) {
    if (/>/) {
        my ($sample, $locus) = ($_ ~= /.*\(Sample_.*\)_\(Locus_.*\)_Allele/);
        if (defined($OUT)) {
          close($OUT);
        }
        open($OUT, "$locus.fa");
        print $OUT ">$sample\n";
    }
    else {
        print $OUT $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I got this error running your script  in Ubuntu (I also added the perl bash and changed to my file name instead of "raw.fa"): "syntax error at line 7 near "$_ ~"

Comment: It should be `=~` instead of `~=`.

Comment: thanks again for the quick help!!!

Comment: With a revised version of the program in [Alain Collins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/677561/alain-collins)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26319829/15168) and with the code from [john smith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2366508/john-smith)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26319941/15168) and a data file of 20,971,520 lines created from the original data repeated a lot of times, I timed the performance of the two scripts. The Perl script using files took almost 37m (whereas it took 22s to create the file), but the Perl script using `system` took 1234m! That's a factor of 33.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file = shift;
my $locusfile;  
open FILE, $file; 
while(<FILE>) 
{
  chomp($_);
  if (/CLocus_([0-9]*)_Sample_([0-9]*)_.*/)
  {
    $locusfile="locus" . $1 . ".fa";
    $cmd = qq{echo ">Sample_$2" >> $locusfile}; 
  }
  else
  {
    $cmd = qq{echo "$_" >> $locusfile};
  }
    system($cmd); 
}
close(FILE);
```

I was unable to append the ">" character at the beginning of the line- got lots of issues when interpolating to the `system` command...so it's not a complete answer but it does what you want.

[FIXED]

Cheers

Comment: i will admit @Alain that your answer was better but I get bonus points for using system() instead...;)

Comment: Wow - that worked beautifully - thanks for the quick response! (my only hang-up as a complete perl novice was knowing to replace "shift" with the name of my file in quotes). I really appreciate it - you've saved this postdoc LOTS of time!!!

Comment: If you must use `system`, then at least get the echoing right.  `$cmd = qq{echo ">Sample_$2" >> $locusfile};` and `$cmd = qq{echo "$_" >> $locusfile};` and put the `system` call after the `if/else`.  I don't think using `system` is a good choice, but it does work.  All else apart, it is expensive — it requires a full shell to be launched for each line of input.  Not a problem when the input is 50 lines, but a significant speed inhibitor if there are 50 million lines.

Comment: FIXED- thanks goes to @JonathanLeffler

Comment: p.s. There are 14,000 lines in my fasta file, so not a problem to wait an hour or so.

Comment: He's right but 14,000 lines is nothing, it should execute quickly

Comment: I ran both programs over 10,000 iterations.  Mine was subsecond, and all those system calls racked up almost a minute.  Fork/exec is a killer!